# What data type is returned by this LocalStorage command?

Tags: qt, local-storage, qml, qtquick2

There is an `LocalStorage` example in the Qt documentation

```
function findGreetings() {
    var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("QQmlExampleDB", "1.0", "The Example QML SQL!", 1000000);

    db.transaction(
        function(tx) {
            // Some other commands

            // Show all added greetings
            var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Greeting');
        }
    )
}
```

What's the data type of `rs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Quick Local Storage QML module documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-localstorage-qmlmodule.html#results-tx-executesql-statement-values):

> ```
> results = tx.executeSql(statement, values)
> ```
>
> This method executes a SQL statement, binding the list of values to
>   SQL positional parameters ("?").
>
> **It returns a results object, with the following properties**:

```
| Type   | Property     | Value                                         | Applicability |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| int    | rows.length  | The number of rows in the result              | SELECT        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| var    | rows.item(i) | Function that returns row i of the result     | SELECT        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| int    | rowsAffected | The number of rows affected by a modification | UPDATE,DELETE |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| string | insertId     | The id of the row inserted                    | INSERT        |
```

Answer (score 2):

> results = tx.executeSql(statement, values)
>
> This method executes a SQL statement, binding the list of values to SQL positional parameters ("?").
> It returns a results object, with the following properties: [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-localstorage-qmlmodule.html#results-tx-executesql-statement-values)

If all you want is to know the type of returned object, just do:

```
var rs = tx.executeSql(...);
console.log(rs); 

qml: [object Object]
```